# Django models field not getting generated in database

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I am creating a basic Django project. I am using the default db sqlite3. I have created an app product inside my main folder. So, my folder structure is like this:

```
-project
  -djangoproject
  -products
    -models.py
-manage.py
```

I am adding my new product model in models.py but when I am running python3 manage.py makemigrations I am checking my migration file. The model is getting created and there is an id field also in it but no other field of my product is coming in my migrations file. I also ran the command python3 manage.py migrations and checked my database. Only id field is present in the product table. I am not able to understand the cause of this problem.

Here is the look at my migration file and models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name: models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price: models.FloatField()
    stock: models.IntegerField()
    image_url: models.CharField(max_length=2083)
```

```
# Generated by Django 5.0.3 on 2024-03-21 04:46

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('products', '0004_delete_offer_delete_product'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Product',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Django version: 5

If anyone knows the reason then please comment or post your answer. It will be really helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have typos in your field declarations where you've used a `:` instead of an `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all migration files, then follow the steps.

**Follow the given step no.**

**step 1 :**

> python manage.py makemigrations appname

**step 2 :**

> python manage.py migrate appname

I hope this solves your problem by following these steps.